# Two equivalent ways to initialize an empty vector in Julia

Tags: arrays, initialization, julia

Are the expressions `Vector{Type}()` and `Type[]` for initializing an empty vector of `Type`s completely equivalent in Julia? Is either syntax preferred?

Comment: I would say that the latter is more "defined on the spot" syntax, whereas the former is more programmatic. This particular example will result in the same, yes, but consider the case `Vector{Int64}(a)`: for `a=0` this is an empty vector, but for any other a it is a vector initialised with garbage values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, they are effectively identical:

```
julia> @code_typed Vector{Any}()
CodeInfo(:(begin
        return $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{Any,1}, svec(Any, Int64), Array{Any,1}, 0, 0, 0))
    end))=>Array{Any,1}

julia> @code_typed Any[]
CodeInfo(:(begin
        return $(Expr(:foreigncall, :(:jl_alloc_array_1d), Array{Any,1}, svec(Any, Int64), Array{Any,1}, 0, 0, 0))
    end))=>Array{Any,1}
```

The `Type[]` syntax is actually just like all other `x[]` syntaxes — it expands to `getindex(Type)`.  And [there you'll see](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/c5dff37ac14f8ece46a9d85b3057c8d64501ae53/base/array.jl#L316) that it's defined in terms of the `Array` constructor.  It's just a convenient shorthand.
I'm not aware of any style guides that prefer one over the other.

Comment: Note that there is currently at least one issue with using `T[]`: see https://discourse.julialang.org/t/performance-issue-with-use-of-eltype/5764 and https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/23618 for more details.

Comment: That's only related to array comprehensions — not empty vector initialization.